# Protect equipment against electromagnetic radiation

Tags: electromagnetism, radiation

They say that in the near future high cosmic radiation is possible. In addition, the Earth’s magnetic field is likely to weaken.
I want to create something like a camera that would protect against electromagnetic radiation. What will be effective for this? Useful articles, real examples? I want to protect equipment, for example, my phones, watches, if at least somehow.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What about protecting yourself first...

Comment: Who is "they", where did they say it and when is this forecast to happen? Do you expect to be alive then?

Comment: I hope we will be alive, given that equipment is more susceptible to electromagnetic radiation. News about magnetic inversion of the Earth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 effects to look out for:

1. Magnetic induction into wiring from e.g. [coronal mass ejections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronal_mass_ejection). The electrical grid is already [largely protected](https://www.nbcnews.com/mach/space/how-we-ll-safeguard-earth-solar-storm-catastrophe-n760021) against these events. To protect equipment in your home, unplug it.
2. Radiation damage, in the event that Earth's magnetic field collapses. In computers, this manifests first as [Single Event Upsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-event_upset): components in a chip that change their state due to being hit by a charged particle. This can corrupt stored data and disrupt operations. Most of these are temporary (the component still works), but occasionally a component can be destroyed if the charged particle has enough energy and the feature size of the chip is small enough.

   There are radiation-tolerant designs (built for the military and for spaceflight applications), but this is not something you can retrofit to an existing design. Your best bet is to disconnect the equipment and bury it - a few meters of water or soil [should be enough](https://what-if.xkcd.com/29/) to protect your equipment.

There is [no indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field#Future) Earth's magnetic field will collapse. Field strength is decreasing at the moment, but that variation is within the normal range.